# how to remove penguins eggs icon from ufficio zero ufficiozero tropea

Tags: linux, icons

so i recently installed ufficio zero tropea and this weird penguins eggs icon keeps popping up every time i login or reboot. Does anyone know how to keep it deleted so it doesn't show up any more?

Comment: I guess by that you mean the [UfficioZero](https://wiki.ufficiozero.org/doku.php?id=tropea) Linux distribution, and "Tropea" appears to be the release name. If found no `UfficioZero` [tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags) on SE, so if there are no `UfficioZero` users around here, maybe ask the same in their [forum](https://forum.ufficiozero.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, normally you can look at **/etc/xdg/autostart/** or in your home, maybe to **.config/autostart/**. In this case culprit is /etc/xdg/autostart/penguin-links-add.desktop, remove this file as root and your icon from desktop.

Comment: i found it thank you!, how do i remove it with the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can use "sudo rm -r /etc/xdg/autostart/penguin-links-add.desktop" without quotes or you can open folder autostart as root and with your dx mouse click on this file->delete

Comment: Isn't this what Adriano [wrote in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/648937/117549)?